# Why getItemCount() called multiple times in recycleView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Pls suggest.
I am unable to find anything written in developer.android.com about this.
If anyone help is highly appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Um, because `RecyclerView` needs to know the count, and the adapter is the "system of record" of the count.

Comment: But why RecyclerView is so desperate for total count even when we just scrolling list. getItemCount() called multiple times even in this case also.

Comment: "But why RecyclerView is so desperate for total count even when we just scrolling list" -- the only way to know when you reach the end of the list is to know how many items there are in the list. Presumably, `RecyclerView` asks the adapter for that.

Answer (score 1):

> getItemCount() - returns The number of items currently available in an
> adapter

This method returns the size of the collection that contains the items you want to display as @CommonsWare said (totally right).

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listofitems.size();
}
```

To give you the searched references take a look here:

- [getItemCount()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.State#getItemCount())
- [The symbiose between LayoutManager and getItemCount()](https://wiresareobsolete.com/2014/09/recyclerview-layoutmanager-2/)

Hope that helps to clarify. Cheers :)